# Are the colors wrong?

Tags: support, design

I know that my eyes are not the best when it comes to color vision.

But all the colors look wrong. Is it just me, is it the Nexus 4 that I'm using, or did someone do something?

Comment: Let me say that if this is intentional, then the design team should really get a couple of colorblind reviewers before rolling out new palettes.

Comment: The user pages seem to be formatted incorrectly at the moment too, at least in Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, something changed in a weird way.  And something seems broken. On the user-pages the "about me" is misplaced.

Comment: I'm not colourblind, and I can barely read them. At recommended viewing distance from my monitor with no glasses it's a blue-green blur, whereas I can read all the other main elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry about that; we imported a bunch of snakes to deal with our parasitic lizard problem, and somehow they took over the page. No one could have predicted this. Fortunately, we lined up a fabulous type of gorilla that thrives on snake meat, and the problem should now be resolved.

[More details on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css/259186#259186)

Comment: I'd use the short-toed eagle for solving the snakes problem. They are magnificent, and they are relatively common in Israel this time of the year. Their Hebrew name is derived from the Arabic name, which literally means "The Snakes Eagle". So they make a good fit for that. I don't know about solving the gorilla problem, but if you had said smaller monkeys, then a harpy eagle is a great solution.

Comment: (I still recommend getting the opinion of one or two color blinded people before rolling out new color schemes, on any site really.)

Answer (score 9):

Me too:

---

[image: Snapshot]