# Help! Help! The colors are off!

Tags: discussion, design

I have a [deja vu](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2325/are-the-colors-wrong).

Are the colors wrong, completely?

Comment: Yes, just like before. And my user page "About me" is wildly misplaced.

Comment: Aagh!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: They better get those short-toed eagles now.

Comment: Perhaps the colors have always been wrong and now they finally are right.

Comment: @quid I don't get it.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: if you click the Asaf's deja vu and read the comments, that'll clear the eagles!

Comment: @ToddTrimble and the summary of questions and so on is now single column, rather than two, for me.

Comment: @Shog9, are you there?

Comment: I've written an email to the SE team. Wait for the cavalry to arrive...

Comment: I'm having a look - stay tuned.

Comment: @quid: I told them not to use the gorillas. That's what happens! :-)

Comment: They seem fixed to me now.

Comment: @David: Yes, it looks that way.

Comment: It seems they are messed again!!

Comment: @Suvrit: I don't see it.

Comment: Weird, they seem off to me, though not as off as yesterday. Maybe I'm hallucinating or maybe this is some CSS issue...